# Accessing servlet context parameters from a CDI extension

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, cdi

I'm trying to write a CDI extension that needs to access the context parameters defined in web.xml via `<context-param>`. I think there are two ways of doing this:

- Somehow get the `ServletContext` and call `getInitParameter()`
- Manually parse the `web.xml`

Unfortunately I need the the `ServletContext` for both solutions and getting it doesn't seem to be possible. The problem here is that some containers startup CDI before the `ServletContext` is created. And even if the `ServletContext` would be available before CDI starts up, there seems to be no way to access it from the CDI extension. I experimented with a `ServletContextListener` that stores the `ServletContext` in a static `ThreadLocal`. This seems to work fine but it would create a memory leak as I'm unable to cleanup the `ThreadLocal` reliably.

Two more comments before you answer:

- Using some other approach to read configuration parameters (like using JNDI) is no option for me as I'm trying to write a CDI extension for integrating with a 3rd party framework.
- I'm aware of the fact that there will be probably no soltion for this problem that is 100% portable between environments/containers. But I would be happy if I find a solution that works in most cases.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

I tried to do something similar with sharing the context with CDI beans in general on JBoss 7.1. Although it didn't work for me, I'm not sure if it's the current state of JBoss7.1 that caused the problems, so perhaps it'll work for you?

What I did was have something on startup that has access to the `ServletContext` (in my case a JAX-RS `Application`, but probably a listener or servlet for you) access an application-scoped bean and set the `ServletContext` in it.

To bridge to the world of CDI, I used the recipe from the following URI to create the bean instance:
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/extend.html#d0e4978

The relevant code is something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getBean(Class<T> instanceClass) throws NamingException 
{
    BeanManager beanManager 
        = (BeanManager) InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/BeanManager");

    AnnotatedType<Object> annotatedType
        = (AnnotatedType<Object>) beanManager.createAnnotatedType(instanceClass);

    InjectionTarget<Object> injectionTarget 
        = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);

    CreationalContext<Object> context
        = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);

    Object instance = injectionTarget.produce(context);

    injectionTarget.inject(instance, context);
    injectionTarget.postConstruct(instance);

    return (T) instance;
}
```

which you could then set into a bean that looks like:

```
package some.package;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

/** An application context, initialised on application startup. */
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppContext 
{

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    /** Return the servlet context for the current application. */
    public ServletContext getServletContext() 
    {
        return servletContext;
    }

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext)
    {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

using a snippet like:

```
getBean(AppContext.class).setServletContext(servletContext);
```

in your startup code.  You should then be able to just `@Inject` the context in whatever CDI construct you want it in... *assuming* it is run after your servlet init or whatever.

For example:

```
@Inject
private AppContext appContext;
```

I'll be curious if this works in other situations...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what container you're using, but it looks like in JBoss at least you can just [inject the ServletContext](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/servlet/latest/reference/en-US/html/injectablerefs.html#injectablerefs.servlet_context) using an annotation. Would this not work for you, or am I not properly understanding the nature of your CDI extension?

EDIT: ah. I've never used the CDI implementation, but would it be possible to create a `ServletContextListener` that generated a CDI event with the `ServletContext` as one of the event properties. You could then just listen for the event in your extension and extract the `ServletContext`.

Comment: An extension is executed during the startup of the CDI implementation. So unfortunately this kind of injection won't work at this early state as the bootstrap process hasn't finished yet.

Comment: No, sorry! Events won't work in this early stage of the CDI startup procedure.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly: you want to access `ServletContext` parameters BEFORE the `ServletContext` has been created? There is no way to wait for the events to fire?

Comment: An CDI extension is executed only during CDI container startup. So waiting is no option. The problem is that SOME containers (e.g. JBoss) bootstrap CDI before the ServletContext is created. In other containers (e.g. Tomcat) there may be the possibility to get a custom ServletContextLister to execute before CDI bootstraps, but I see no option to "store" the ServletContext somewhere, where I can access it from the extension. You see the situation is tricky! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed yourself and Femi commented if the ServletContext is not available there is no way you can get anything from it (like init params).
Reading web.xml file is possible but for sure it's crazy and won't be portable, but you can always try to do it on your specific deployment, you can get an example of reading smth from WEB-INF [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?19659-read-a-resource-file-in-WEB-INF)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think you are right that manually parsing web.xml is the only option. However I think its difficult to get an InputStream for web.xml without ServletContext. Any idea how to do this?